# How to find which kinds are not being used in Google Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

There's any way to list the kinds that are not being used in google's datastore by our app engine app without having to look into our code and/or logic? : )

I'm not talking about indexes, which I can list by issuing an

```
gcloud datastore indexes list
```

and then compare with the datastore-indexes.xml or index.yaml.

I tried to check datastore kinds statistics and other metadata but I could not find anything useful to help me on this matter.

Should I give up to find ways of datastore providing me useful stats and code something to keep collecting datastore statistics(like data size), during a huge period to have at least a clue of which kinds are not being used and then, only after this research, take a look into our app code to see if the kind Model was removed?
Example:

```
select bytes from __Stat_Kind__
```

Store it somewhere and keep updating for a period. If the Kind bytes size does not change than probably the kind is not being used anymore.

The idea is to do some cleaning in datastore.
I would like to find which *kinds* are not being used anymore, maybe for a long time or were created manually to be used once... You know, like a table in oracle that no one knows what is used for and then if we look into the statistics of that table we would see that this table was only used once 5 years ago. I'm trying to achieve the same in datastore, I want to know which *kinds* are not being used anymore or were used a while ago, then ask around and backup/delete it if no owner was found.

Comment: Could you give a reproducible sample of what you're trying to achieve? I'm trying to understand what your expected output should look like. I was thinking that you can use GQL to achieve it. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference

Comment: Hey Donald, thx for your comment. I added more info to the question. Please let me know if it's better now. ^^

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question.

I think you would be best-placed to audit your code and instill organizational practice that requires this documentation to be performed in future as a business|technical pre-prod requirement.

IIRC, Datastore doesn't automatically timestamp Entities and keys (rightly) aren't incremental. So there appears no intrinsic mechanism to track changes short of taking a snapshot (expensive) and comparing your in-flight and backup copies for changes (also expensive and inconclusive).

One challenge with identifying a Kind that appears to be non-changing is that it could be referenced (rarely) by another Kind and so, while it does not change, it is required.

Auditing your code and documenting it for posterity should not only provide you with a definitive answer (and identify owners) but it pays off a significant technical debt that has been incurred and avoids this and probably future problems (e.g. GDPR-like) requirements that will arise in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to **records being created/updated**, then I can think of the following options

1. Via the Cloud Console (Datastore > Dashboard) - This lists all your 'Kinds' and the number of records in each Kind. Theoretically, you can take a screen shot and compare the counts so that you know which one has experienced an increase or not.
2. Use of Created/LastModified Date columns - I usually add these 2 columns to most of my datastore tables. If you have them, then you can have a stored function that queries them. For example, you run a query to  sort all of your Kinds in descending order of creation (or last modified date) and you only pull the first record from each one. This tells you the last time a record was created or modified.

I would write a function as part of my App, put it behind a page which requires admin privilege (only app creator can run it) and then just clicking a link on my App would give me the information.